# Новая переменная в цикле while

Tags: javascript, while

Подскажите, как в моем случае передавать в анонимную функцию новое значение переменной position в цикле. С let работает, но хотелось бы правильно организовать мой случай, где очевидно, что position принимает одно и тоже значение для всех функций.

```
var data = [];
var arr = [];

while(true) {

    var position = data.push(Math.random()) - 1; 

    addFunction (function () {
        data[position] = 0;
    })

    if (data.length>9) break;
}

function addFunction(fn) {
    arr.push(fn);
}

setTimeout(function(){
    arr.forEach(item => item())
},2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение понял сам, в данном случае анонимная функция не справляется с задачей:

```
var data = [];
var arr = [];

while(true) {

    var position = data.push(Math.random()) - 1; 

    addPosition(data,position)

    if (data.length>9) break;
}

function addFunction(fn) {
    arr.push(fn);
}

function addPosition(data,position) {
    addFunction (function () {
        data[position] = 0;
    })  
}

setTimeout(function(){
    arr.forEach(item => item())
},2000)
```